# How to use fwrite to output an xts object with ISO DateTime and custom timeZone?

Tags: r, data.table

I recently discovered `fwrite` which I can use instead of `write.zoo` to write data. fwrite is much faster, about 60 times or 1 second vs 1 minute.
My only issue with fwrite is that it writes dateTime in ISO format vs the write.zoo.
zoo (which does not even output the timezone)

```
11/30/2017  5:40:02 PM
```

ISO

```
2017-11-30T23:40:02Z
```

I found some fwrite documentation [Here](https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/fwrite.html) which describes an option for `dateTimeAs = "write.csv"` it outputs exactly as write.zoo, which is great, but it now takes 4 seconds which is still much faster than write.zoo, but 4 times slower than ISO and I now want the speed of the ISO option. I have issue with ISO, I just need to be in my proper timezone which in my case is "America/Chicago"

ISO is the default option with UTC time zone. But ISO supports an output with any timezone by adding an offset instead of the Z at the end.

So finally, how can I change the timezone for fwrite ISO format, assuming that it is possible.

Comment: I think asking for an offset option to get +0600 instead of Z in your case is a feature request. The way to get this seen by the maintainers and developers is to tag it correctly.

Comment: "America/Chicago" is not always 6 hours depending on daylight savings. As the feature request, does that mean that fwrite cannot write anything other than UTC, without the write.csv option? Thanks.

Comment: That's how I read the help page and their comments on github. Looks to me that they endorse always using UTC as the least error prone strategy. I added the `[data.table]` tag so that Matt or Arun would see this.

Comment: would Sys.setenv(TZ='your timezone') help?

Comment: Thank you, my environment TZ is set correctly and it does not work is as expected. The only thing I can think of is if ISO has a specific way to set timezone which also has not worked. If this is a feature request, can someone help me make the request?